# Is it possible to create an empty Visual Studio solution from the command line?

Tags: visual-studio

Initializing Visual Studio solutions is painful in that it always seems to want to put things under my Documents directory, and it never seems to lay out the directories the way I want.

Is it possible to initialize an empty solution via the command line?  Basically, I want the equivalent of `yo aspnet`, but for pre-vNext code.

Comment: Copy emptytemplate.sln to myapplication.sln?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to simply create an empty template.sln and file copy it to the destination.

Platforms and Configurations don't exist until you have at least 1 project in the solution.  There might also be some more stuff that you want to configure for SCC bindings and so on.

FWIW, I understand from previous experience what you mean.  Personally I've adopted directory structures and naming conventions based on what VS wants to natively push me towards.  I've worked at companies where the declared standard was not in line with this and starting with an empty SLN file was a good starting place for that to work.

Example empty SLN file:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 14
VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.23107.0
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Comment: Are there any GUIDs in solution files that are important and have to generated new every time you new up a solution?

Comment: SCC == version control?

Comment: Yes, SCC in this context refers back to source control meta as seen at the bottom of here compared to my empty example above. http://iswix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#main/Source/Application/Application.sln

Comment: There are no guids in an empty solution.  The guids are artifacts of the projects when they get created.